# Weird exception thrown when using simulavr with avr-gdb

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, avr, avr-gcc

I am debugging a program that I have written for the AVR architecture and compiled using `avr-gcc` with the `-g` argument.

I launch `simulavr` using the following command: `simulavr --device atmega8 --gdbserver`

Then I invoke `avr-gdb` and do `(gdb) file main.elf` as well as `(gdb) target remote localhost:1212`

Once debugging has started, I can successfully `step` through the assembly portion of my program `.init` et al. However, once `jmp main` is executed and a call to another function is made, `simulavr` throws the following exception: `Assertion failed: (m_on_call_sp != 0x0000), function OnCall, file hwstack.cpp, line 266. Abort trap: 6`

It has something to do with the pushing a frame to the stack, but I can't quite put my finger on how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

That stack value is very far from what it should be. At the start of your program, it should be near the end of RAM, not at the beginning.

It is likely to be some problem with simulavr not configuring RAM properly for your device. A quick look for the source code shows that the stack pointer is set to 0 if the simulator can't determine the correct value.

Did you include -mmcu=atmega8 in the command line when compiling? Try adding -V switch to the simulavr command for more clues.

Comment: The `-V` argument doesn't yield anything useful. I'm still getting the exception. To answer your question, yes, I am compiling with `-mmcu=` but I am actually compiling for the `atmega8u2`. The underlying architectures of each chip are identical, so I don't see how it would be an issue.